# Cakephp save radio

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there any option to save choosen radio instantly as an action ? I'm trying something like this, but without success.

```
<?php

 if (isset($this->request->data['Answer']['answer'])) 
            { 
                //$this->request->data['Answer']['question_id'] = $data['Question']['id'];
                $this->request->data['Answer']['member_id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
                if($this->Answer->save($this->request->data))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

without isset it's working but no value is assing from my radio button.

here is mpart of my view.

```
<?php $this->Form->create('Answer'); ?>
            1.<?php echo 'A.'.$answers[0]; 
                $options = array($answers[0] => '');
                $attributes = array('label'=>false,'separator'=>'<br>');
                echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes); echo '<br>'?>
            2.<?php echo 'B.'.$answers[1]; 
                $options = array($answers[1] => '');
                $attributes = array('label'=>false,'separator'=>'<br>');
                echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes); echo '<br>'?>
            3.<?php echo 'C.'.$answers[2]; 
                $options = array($answers[2] => '');
                $attributes = array('label'=>false,'separator'=>'<br>');
                echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes); echo '<br>'?>
            4.<?php echo 'D.'.$answers[3]; 
                $options = array($answers[3] => '');
                $attributes = array('label'=>false,'separator'=>'<br>');
                echo $this->Form->radio('gender', $options, $attributes); echo '<br>'?>
       <?php $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Give code of how you posted data

Comment: updated (input radio).
Main problem is, how to save data from radio after changing the page ?

Comment: you should not use $_POST directly, you generally do not have to, as it may break things for CakePHP, and introduce security holes

Comment: so instead of $_POST should be smth like $this->data['a'] ?

Comment: instead of $_POST you should use if(isset($this->request->data['Answer'])) {

Comment: I think it is related to the way you wrote your form in the view. This  should begin with something like  `$this->Form->create('Answer')`. Post the view if you can.

Comment: all is now updated.
Is there any way to save that radio after change page without save button ?

Comment: Sounds like you need some js. Your CakePHP code looks pretty messy/unconventional, making the question hard to understand.

Comment: yea,, i agree with you, i had my old controller, now i updated it

Comment: To save individual fields, use saveField function http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false